# jvisualvm not showing any information about my application packages when profiling

Tags: profiling, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am using **jvisualvm** in order to profile my application.

My application base package is **`com.bignibou`**

I have added the following settings in jvisualvm's "*Profile only packages*" field:

```
com.bignibou.*, org.springframework.*
```

I noticed that only the org.springframework.* packages and sub-packages show in the "*cpu samples*" for the Tomcat process...

Can anyone please help me understand why no information is shown about my application packages?

Comment: Note: for some reason, the chosen scenario did not show any data for my application base package. However when I chose another scenario, it did show a hotspot method based on my application package in the cpu samples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "Start Profiling from Classes" to "com.bignibou.**" and uncheck "Profile new Runnables". You can set "Profile only packages" back to its default. More details about profiling settings can be found in [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 1](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1) and [Profiling With VisualVM, Part 2](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_2).